# I'm trying to make my baseplate respawn. (Roblox Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to get my part to respawn after it's unanchored, I've tried to look it up on Youtube but I had no luck.

What I'm trying to do is after it unanchored it will respawn after 10 seconds and repeat the process.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question as text instead of an image

Comment: I tried to but it only let me put 1 line of script and I couldn't paste it

Comment: Start and end the code block with triple back-ticks: https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks

Comment: Do you need the Baseplate to fall? Or do you just need the players to fall to their doom?

Comment: I'm trying to make them fall to their death. Also, is using destroy easier?

Comment: I am just going to make the baseplate move positions instead of destroying so it can be used again easily, the only problem is that I need my script to repeat/loop infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw the Baseplate into ServerStorage for it to be moved back to the Workspace.

```lua
local part = game.Workspace.Baseplate
-- Remove baseplate:
part.Parent = game.ServerStorage
-- Then to put baseplate back:
part.Parent = game.Workspace
```

Full code

```lua
local part = game.Workspace.Baseplate
wait(5)
for i = 0, 0.9, 0.1 do
    part.Transparency = i
    wait(1)
end
part.Transparency = 1
part.Parent = game.ServerStorage
wait(10)
part.Parent = game.Workspace
for i = 0.9, 0, -0.1 do
    part.Transparency = i
    wait(1)
end
```

Please note that in the statement to unanchor the part was removed; it is unnecessary and causes problems.

Comment: Since you removed the unanchoring behaviour, why not just make the baseplate's CanCollide value false?

Comment: @Kylaaa because OP wants the baseplate completely gone from client view as far as I can tell

Comment: Was about to answer with something that looked close to this. If OP is reading this then this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's write your code like a programmer. You don't have to hardcode those transparency values.

```
local part = game.Workspace.Baseplate
wait(5)
for i = 0.1, 0.9, 0,1 do
  part.transparency = i
  wait(1)
end
part.transparency = 1
part.Anchored = false
wait(10)
```

I'm no Roblox expert but spawning parts seems to be just a matter of setting a part's parent. So to respawn something it is probably sufficient to remove and set the Parent property of part and wait in between.

Try something like

```
Baseplate.Parent = nil
wait(1)
Baseplate.Parent = game.Workspace
```

Comment: Your code does not work, I've tried it in the baseplate and in the workspace.

Comment: When they set the "Anchored" property to false, gravity takes it until it hits a kill-plane around -500 studs on the y-axis, at which point the part gets Destroyed. So setting the parent won't bring it back. But one modification you could make is to Clone() the baseplate, set the clone's parent to ReplicatedStorage, and then re-parenting the clone into the Workspace after the wait().